# Is it possible to create HyperLink using QuickReport's QRLabel

Tags: delphi, quickreports

In a Delphi based application, we are using QuickReport as reporting tool.
As per new requirement, website addresses and email addresses in generated PDF has to be act as hyperlinks

We use QRLabel to display most of the static information. 
Is it possible to convert QRLabel's content as hyperlink, so that when user clicks on the static information, user shall be redirected to the respective web page ?

Is there any other QuickReport components to add a HyperLink to a PDF ?
Version info:- Using Delphi 10.2 and QuickReport 6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sucks that this is the only search result I can find, which has no answer. My search keeps assuming I want a "URL" or "Hyperlink" to information about QuickReports...